# PHP Nested JSON encoding joining arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested

I'm new to JSON and trying to join two PHP arrays and output the result as JSON.  I ran the output into a JSON validator and it said it was ok but I'm not convinced.  How can I replace the "0" on line 4 of the output to be "genres" and will the output be easy to pull out each genre name by the receiver?

```
{
"apiVersion": "1.0",
"status": "ok",
"0": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Miscellaneous",
        "like": "NO"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Breakbeat",
        "like": "NO"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Trance",
        "like": "NO"
    },  etc....
```

Here is my code;

```
    $data = array(
    "apiVersion"=>"1.0",
    "status"=> "ok"
);

$i = 0;
foreach ($exploded as $item) {
    $e_row[] = array(
        "id" => $i,
        "name" => $item,
        "like" => "NO"     
    );
    $i = $i + 1;
} 

array_push($data,$e_row);

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: `array_push($data,$e_row);` => `$data['genres'] = $e_row;`

Comment: Actually you don't need that if you do `$data['genres'][] = array(` in the loop.

Comment: And what does this mean _will the output be easy to pull out each genre name by the receiver?_